# COM Object - Array as Object instead of Type

Tags: c#, vba, com, interop

Im developing a COM object in C#, VS 2010, .Net 3.5, x86

I used to have a array of structs in the COM Object, which in VBA showed up fine with all the fields and everything.

I switched to class since It created some issues.
Now how ever I cant access the properties in the array, since the elements in the array show up as object instead of type.

```
[Guid("8b65079f-5d98-41e7-9579-1ee384948e4c")]
[ComVisible(true)]
public interface IContact
{
    string Test1 { get; set; }
    string[] Array1 { get; set; }
}

[Guid("8b65089f-5d98-41e7-9579-1ee384948e4c")]
[ComVisible(true)]
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.AutoDual)]
public class Contact : IContact //Used To Be a struct
{
    //[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)]
    public string Test1 { get; set; }
    public string[] Array1 { get; set; }
}

public class InContainer
{

        public Contact[] Contacts { get;set;}
        public string[] strings { get; set; }
}
```

In the debugger I see when viewing the field:

Container.Contacts() -> (0 To 4) As Object

instead of

Container.Contacts() -> (0 To 4) As Contact

What am i missing? Thanks!

Comment: That´s one of the caveats when working with COM, you don´t see what´s *inside*. Btw.: why is this question tagged C#?

Comment: The com object is written in C#
But I saw what was inside when it was a struct, and I have no issue with other classes

Comment: I think even in VBA you can use typeof to test the object type. Might be worth a go.

Comment: Can you show your VBA code?

Answer (score 2):

Here are some things you can check:

1. Make sure your container class is correctly declared (I guess it is already COM-visible, but that's not shown in your sample:

   ```
   [Guid("EA34C9D6-3EAA-4D44-A8BA-81CC2E79090B")]
   [ComVisible(true)]
   [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.AutoDual)]
   public class InContainer
   ```
2. Correctly register your assembly using the correct version of regasm (probably you need the 32-bit one) with the `/codebase` switch:

   ```
   regasm /codebase <myassembly.dll>
   ```
3. In VBA, instantiate your container, e.g. using late-binding:

   ```
   Sub Test()
       Dim a As Object
       Set a = CreateObject("Issue40977311.InContainer")
   End Sub
   ```

   This results in the correct types being shown:

   [image]

   Alternatively, you can also create a type library using the `/tlb` switch of regasm:

   ```
   regasm /codebase <myassembly.dll> /tlb
   ```

   and the add the reference to the created .tlb file in VBA via *Tools > References > Browse*. You can then instantiate your object as follows:

   ```
   Sub Test()
       Dim a As Object
       Set a = New Issue40977311.InContainer
   End Sub
   ```